# unable to display inserted Hindi value from android app in mysql database table

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm inserting hindi value into mysql database using php insert script

android insert code

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data1","माऊली"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data2","माऊली"));    


            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.mydemo.com/insert.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
```

insert.php code

```
<?php
    $host='100.111.111.11';
    $uname='tempdata';
    $pwd='tempdata';
    $db="tempdata";


    $con = mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("connection failed");
    mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die("db selection failed");

    $data1=$_REQUEST['data1'];
    $data2=$_REQUEST['data2'];


    $flag['code']=0;
mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'", $con);

    if($r=mysql_query("insert into test values('$data1','$data2') ",$con))
    {
        $flag['code']=1;        
    }

    print(json_encode($flag));
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

insertion is successful but values looks like `?????`  in mysql database table

If same code I execute like following
`'$r=mysql_query("insert into test values('माऊली','माऊली') ",$con)'`

It display correct word 'माऊली'

any clue what need to be modify ?

Comment: What is `default charset` of your `mysql database` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the ans need to pass extra parameter as sending value we need to encode it into UTF8

```
 httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(body, HTTP.UTF_8));
```

thanks for helping :)